# Rhino mocks stubbing twice the same function doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, rhino-mocks

I've started to work with Rhino recently and encountered a very unexpected behavior that I couldn't overcome.

The issue is that I have an infrastructure of my stubs and in one of my tests I needed to change one of the predefined stubs (in my infrastructure) to return a different value then the default one.

I've reproduce the issue in the following code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private IWorker _worker;

    [SetUp]
    void Setup()
    {
        _worker = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IWorker>();
        _worker.Stub(w=>w.DoWork()).Return(0);
    }

    [Test]
    public void DoWork_StubbingFunctionTwice_CallingTheLastStub()
    {
        int expected = 1;
        _worker.Stub(w => w.DoWork()).Return(expected);
        int actual =_worker.DoWork();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

}

public interface IWorker
{
    int DoWork();
}
```

someone knows why the Rhino stubs are behaving this way and more important how can I solve it in the cleanest way?

Comment: This behavior caught me out out. I was reusing a mock object in a number of tests. I one test that needed the mock to reproduce a different result for one of the stubbed properties, so I just tried to 'overwrite' the previous property stub, but as explained below, it doesn't quite work like this. My solution was to create a separate mock object instead of reusing the existing one, but I appreciate that that might not be appropriate in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify a behavior on a fake object in `RhinoMocks` without any constraint(RepeatOnce and etc..) the behavior will stay and you won't be able to override it.(actually option 1 shows how you can...)

In your case you specify a specific behavior in the `Setup` method:

```
_worker.Stub(w=>w.DoWork()).Return(0);
```

The above line will execute before `_worker.Stub(w => w.DoWork()).Return(expected);`.

The best practice for `SetUp` / `TestInitialize` attributes is to group inside them **only** settings which you want to apply in **all test methods**.

By default any method with a return value returns the `default(T)` so you can remove `_worker.Stub(w=>w.DoWork()).Return(0);` and then any thing will work.

If your real case is more complex:

**Option1**: clear the mock

```
// clear expectations, an enum defines which
_worker.BackToRecord(BackToRecordOptions.All);

// go to replay again.
_worker.Replay();
```

**Option2**: limit the behavior

```
_worker.Stub(w=>w.DoWork()).Return(0).Repeat.Once(); // or the max time you need...
```

and then add a loop inside the test method:

```
for(...; i < num of time; ...)
    _worker.DoWork();
```

**Option3**: create a new fake and CUT(class under test)